# Firebase Crashlytics for Android does not work

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to install Firebase Crashlytics on my Android application. I've never used it before.

Apparently the docs are not complete because doing everything step by step does not help to enable Crashlytics - https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=0

I tried force initializing it with `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` added to `onCreate()` of my Application class. Didn't help.

Logs:

```
06-06 19:53:01.750 2946-2946/my.package I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.3.25
06-06 19:53:02.572 2946-3015/my.package E/Fabric: Settings request failed.
06-06 19:53:02.590 2946-3010/my.package E/Answers: Failed to retrieve settings
```

Any ideas what's wrong? Maybe it's internal Firebase issue and it broke globally? Something is wrong here.

Comment: If you're having problems setting up Crashlytics, please contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Ok. I've done it. Let's see. I suspect some account issue. All was implemented right.

Comment: It looks like Crashlytics cannot work for system privileged apps. My app is installed in `/system/priv-app`. Operating system is Lineage 15.1. Nobody from Firebase was able to help. It may be either Lineage bug or the fact that it is a system app.

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. We haven't tested against forks of Android, so it's entirely possible that something has changed which prevents Crashlytics from working for your app.

Comment: You know what? It magically started to work. Just like that. All is perfect now. Lol. So it's solved :)